# Unable to prepare context: path "***.dkr.ecr.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com.." error in Github Action

Tags: amazon-web-services, github-actions, amazon-ecr

Trying to push image to AWS ECR with github action but having errors while deploying

I used the following steps:

```
jobs:
  build-and-push:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2
    - uses: docker://ghcr.io/kciter/aws-ecr-action:latest
      with:
        access_key_id: ${{ secrets.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID }}
        secret_access_key: ${{ secrets.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY }}
        account_id: ${{ secrets.AWS_ACCOUNT_ID }}
        repo: docker/repo
        region: ap-northeast-2
        tags: latest,${{ github.sha }}
        create_repo: true
        image_scanning_configuration: true
        set_repo_policy: true
        repo_policy_file: repo-policy.json
```

Answer (score 0):

The error arises from using latest docker image.

Replace  `- uses: docker://ghcr.io/kciter/aws-ecr-action:latest`
with

`kciter/aws-ecr-action@v3`